# How to get the reverse encoding of text generated by GOOGLE UNIVERSAL Sentence encoder?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp

I have generated an embedded matrix using google universal sentence encoder and now I need to reconstruct the text. I wonder if that is possible?